# PUT requests in Wildfly respond with 500

Tags: wildfly

I have an app with a backend and a frontend that communicate with each other, and is developed on Wildfly.

When I make a PUT request from the backend to the frontend, these requests do not arrive and they return a 500 error. However, POST requests work correctly and do not generate problems.

I have checked the configuration of the wildfly, ficher or configuration server (standalone.xml), but I do not fall where the problem may be.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you add some of your code that isn't working so we can help debug?

Comment: You should first identify whether it's Wildfly or Apache that is replying with the HTTP 500. Check if you can find the 500 in Wildfly's logs, if not then it must be Apache that sends it. You can also try to send your request to Wildfly directly to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

So you say when the backend sends a PUT request the response has status 500, while when the backend sends a POST request to the same URL the response has status 2XX?

That does not smell like a connectivity issue. It seems more that your PUT request gets blocked somewhere. Try to find out where that error 500 is coming from. It could be a proxy or firewall inbetween client and server, it could be even that Wildfly or the application are not configured to respond to PUT.